# How to localize TextAngular tooltips

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, textangular

Is there any possibility to pass custom tooltips strings to the `TextAngular` editor (http://textangular.com/)? Having English tooltips in a non-English app looks unready and unprofessional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the tooltips that appear when hovering over the items in the toolbar, then you can modify textAngularSetup.js to provide the translations you want to use.

@line 81 of that file there is a section that provides the text for each of the buttons' tooltips.

```
.value('taTranslations', {
// moved to sub-elements
//toggleHTML: "Toggle HTML",
//insertImage: "Please enter a image URL to insert",
//insertLink: "Please enter a URL to insert",
//insertVideo: "Please enter a youtube URL to embed",
html: {
    tooltip: 'Toggle html / Rich Text'
},
// tooltip for heading - might be worth splitting
heading: {
    tooltip: 'Heading '
},
p: {
    tooltip: 'Paragraph'
},
pre: {
    tooltip: 'Preformatted text'
},
ul: {
    tooltip: 'Unordered List'
},
ol: {
    tooltip: 'Ordered List'
},
quote: {
    tooltip: 'Quote/unquote selection or paragraph'
},
undo: {
    tooltip: 'Undo'
},
redo: {
    tooltip: 'Redo'
},
bold: {
    tooltip: 'Bold'
},
italic: {
    tooltip: 'Italic'
},
underline: {
    tooltip: 'Underline'
},
strikeThrough:{
    tooltip: 'Strikethrough'
},
justifyLeft: {
    tooltip: 'Align text left'
},
justifyRight: {
    tooltip: 'Align text right'
},
justifyCenter: {
    tooltip: 'Center'
},
indent: {
    tooltip: 'Increase indent'
},
outdent: {
    tooltip: 'Decrease indent'
},
clear: {
    tooltip: 'Clear formatting'
},
insertImage: {
    dialogPrompt: 'Please enter an image URL to insert',
    tooltip: 'Insert image',
    hotkey: 'the - possibly language dependent hotkey ... for some future implementation'
},
insertVideo: {
    tooltip: 'Insert video',
    dialogPrompt: 'Please enter a youtube URL to embed'
},
insertLink: {
    tooltip: 'Insert / edit link',
    dialogPrompt: "Please enter a URL to insert"
},
editLink: {
    reLinkButton: {
        tooltip: "Relink"
    },
    unLinkButton: {
        tooltip: "Unlink"
    },
    targetToggle: {
        buttontext: "Open in New Window"
    }
},
wordcount: {
    tooltip: 'Display words Count'
},
    charcount: {
    tooltip: 'Display characters Count'
}
})
```

Edit each of those and you should be good to go.